# How to filter datatable by integers range?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've a dataTable in my JSF page where I list all my object. Usually I use the filterBy and filterMatchMode to perform this type of operation, but in this case I have to filter the list for a given column, for a range of value. How Can I achieve this?

```
<p:dataTable id="dtOrders" var="productionOrder"
                        value="#{productionOrdersView.orders}" selectionMode="single"
                        reflow="true" selection="#{productionOrdersView.selected}"
                        filteredValue="#{productionOrdersView.filtered}"
                        widgetVar="ordersTable" rowKey="#{productionOrder.pk}"
                        paginator="true" rows="20">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                           Bolle di lavorazione
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column headerText="Numero bolla"
                            sortBy="#{productionOrder.orderNumber}"
                            filterFunction="#{productionOrdersView.filter()}"
                            filterOptions="contains">
                            <f:facet name="filter">
                                <h:inputHidden id="filter" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Numero bolla" />
                                <h:outputText value="Dalla" />
                                <p:inputText id="from"
                                    value="#{productionOrdersView.orderNumberStartFilter}">
                                    <p:ajax event="keyup" />
                                </p:inputText>
                                <h:outputText value="alla" />
                                <p:inputText id="to"
                                    value="#{productionOrdersView.orderNumberEndFilter}">
                                    <p:ajax event="change"
                                        listener="#{productionOrdersView.filter()}" update="dtOrders"
                                        oncomplete="PF('dtOrders').filter()" />
                                </p:inputText>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{productionOrder.orderNumber}" />
                        </p:column>
```

And the bean method:

```
public void filter() {
    System.out.println("Filtering...");
    System.out.println(orderNumberStartFilter+" "+orderNumberEndFilter);
    if(orderNumberStartFilter!=null && orderNumberEndFilter!=null) {
        this.filtered = productionOrderController.findFromToOrderNumber(Integer.valueOf(orderNumberStartFilter), Integer.valueOf(orderNumberEndFilter));
    }else {
        if(orderNumberStartFilter!=null) {
            this.filtered = productionOrderController.findFromToOrderNumber(Integer.valueOf(orderNumberStartFilter), Integer.valueOf(orderNumberStartFilter));
            return;
        }
        if(orderNumberEndFilter!=null) {
            this.filtered = productionOrderController.findFromToOrderNumber(Integer.valueOf(orderNumberEndFilter), Integer.valueOf(orderNumberEndFilter));
            return;
        }
        this.filtered = orders;
    }
    System.out.println(filtered.size());
}
```

How Can I filter the list? Is this a good approach to perform this operation? Also I want that if just one value is inserted, the filter operation is made equals (so exact that order). I've search on the web and I've seen a lot of example for date, but nothing for integer values.

**Update**

```
    list.xhtml:72 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at Object.onco (list.xhtml:72)
    at Object.<anonymous> (core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:3)
    at u (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:2)
    at k (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:2)
onco @ list.xhtml:72
(anonymous) @ core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:3
u @ jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:2
fireWith @ jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:2
k @ jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:2
```

Comment: You can do something like that
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml
And make your own filter. Look the filter in price

Comment: Thank you, but there is just one value! In my case I want a range, so two values (max and min) @tsotzolas

Comment: Ok I found the javascript error. Change the `PF('dtOrders').filter()` with `PF('ordersTable').filter()`. I also change and my answer. You must put there the widgetVar value

Comment: Also does this change, but the values are not updated, whereas the system output is just 2 values

Comment: The values is not updated because you put in datable value not the filtered values but the primarily list. In `p:datatable` the field `filteredValue` is to TAKE the filtered values from the table and not to put the values that you filter in your method. https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/datatable

Comment: Could you please modify your anwser with the correct one?

Comment: Let's discuss here please.
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200919/discussion-between-tsotzolas-and-i-love-coding

Answer (score 0):

Make your code like that

The xhtml

```
 <p:column headerText="Order number" sortBy="#{productionOrder.orderNumber}"
      filterFunction="#{productionOrdersView.filter()}"
      filterMatchMode="contains">
          <f:facet name="filter">
               <h:inputHidden id="filter"/>
          </f:facet>
          <f:facet name="header">
      <p:inputText id="from" value="#{productionOrdersView.from}">
          <p:ajax event="keyup" />
      </p:inputText>
      <h:outputText class="fa fa-arrows-h fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"/>
     <p:inputText id="to" value="#{productionOrdersView.to}">
          <p:ajax event="change"  
               listener="#{productionOrdersView.filter()}" update="your_dataTable_Id" 
               oncomplete="PF('your_dataTable_widgetVar').filter()"/>
      </p:inputText>
           </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{productionOrdersView.orderNumber}" />
  </p:column>
```

In the bean make 2 Integer variables `from` `to` with getter and setter and make o method to filter your data

```
 private Integer from;
 private Integer to;
 ..............

 //Method that filter the data
 public void filter(){
   //Filter your data between from - to 
 .......................
    }
}
```

You can improve this code but I think it is a good base.

---

### UPDATE ANSWER

The problem with your code is that you don't put the filtered list as a value in your datatable.
To work this code You can do 2 things. (**Do one of them**)
1) Change the filtered function as below.

```
public void filter() {
System.out.println("Filtering...");
System.out.println(orderNumberStartFilter+" "+orderNumberEndFilter);
if(orderNumberStartFilter!=null && orderNumberEndFilter!=null) {
    this.filtered = productionOrderController.findFromToOrderNumber(Integer.valueOf(orderNumberStartFilter), Integer.valueOf(orderNumberEndFilter));
}else {
    if(orderNumberStartFilter!=null) {
        orders = productionOrderController.findFromToOrderNumber(Integer.valueOf(orderNumberStartFilter), Integer.valueOf(orderNumberStartFilter));
        return;
    }
    if(orderNumberEndFilter!=null) {
        orders = productionOrderController.findFromToOrderNumber(Integer.valueOf(orderNumberEndFilter), Integer.valueOf(orderNumberEndFilter));
        return;
    }

}
System.out.println(orders.size());
```

}

2) Change the variable in datatable value code.

```
<p:dataTable id="dtOrders" var="productionOrder"
                    value="#{productionOrdersView.filtered}" selectionMode="single"
                    reflow="true" selection="#{productionOrdersView.selected}"
                    widgetVar="ordersTable" rowKey="#{productionOrder.pk}"
                    paginator="true" rows="20">
  .................
```

Comment: Thank you but I've god some problems with the update method; where am I wrong? I've updated my questions.

Comment: The filter method is working well?Is filtering the date with the inputs numbers?If you update the whole form and not only `dtOrders` is working?

Comment: The method filter() works, since the console output is 2 (this is correct since I've entered two continuous number, but the the table show the entire items and not only the 2 item

Comment: The value of the datatable must be the `filtered` values.
So is better in the filter to put the `orders` and not the `filtered` 
The `filteredValue` is a list that you can have the values after the filter

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the filter() method is the filtered list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200919/discussion-between-tsotzolas-and-i-love-coding).

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but it doesn't change. Also I've noticed the console error from Chrome reported in the questions!